# Decades Bucket Fill C Program

Tags: c

You are given the birth years of fifteen random people who were born in the twentieth century (1900 - 1999). You are given the data as the following array, which is to be the only argument used in your BucketSort function:

`birthYears[] = {84, 51, 92, 72, 17, 62, 1, 16, 10, 28, 99, 71, 45, 18, 61};`

Your function will have return type void and will work in the following manner:

•   Create a 10x 10 array, which will represent the decades, and call it decade. Thus, `decade[0][1]` -> `decade[0][9]` will represent the 00’s, `decade[1][0]` -> `decade[1][9]` will represent the 10’s, and so on up to `decade[9][0]` -> `decade[9][9]` which will represent the 90’s.
•   Initialize your array so that it contains only -1’s.
•   Now go through the array `birthYears` and put each element in its appropriate bucket, and in its appropriate index (WATCH THE INDICES) in your decade array.
•   Finally, trawl through decades, removing the elements one at a time and put back into the array birthYears. They should already be in the correct order.

This is what I have so far:

```
void Bucket_Sort(birthYears[]){  
    int i,j;    
    int decades[10][10];
    for(i=0; i<15; i++)
}

//Actual Bucket Sort Function

void Bucket_Sort(int array[], int n){  
    int i, j;  
    int count[n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        count[i] = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        (count[array[i]])++;

    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < n; i++)  
        for(; count[i] > 0; (count[i])--)
           array[j++] = i;
}
```

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: So do you want to sort the array?

Comment: Basically. I have to use bucket sort to sort it. But then I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: Did your teacher state anything about using `qsort`?

Comment: Nope. The question states to use bucket sort.

Comment: But do you know what it is? Also, fix your post, it messed up on formatting.

Comment: Oh thanks for the formatting help. But the problem is I have the bucket sort function above, and I am not sure how to proceed with solving the problem.

Comment: This is going to be slightly difficult due to the multi-dimensional array. If it was a single array, it would have been a lot easier with a normal array when using bucket sort. If you didn't need to use that method, then I can give you an idea on how to do it.

Comment: Sure. I'd be fine with doing the single array method you could show me.

Comment: If you are gonna do a single array meaning `array[10]` and not `array[10[10]`, you can easily do it with the bucket sort method.

Comment: Okay thank you. Can I just use this bucket sort function, to do the sorting : http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-sorts-array-using-bucket-sort/

Comment: Next time, don't put the whole code in the comment. Yes, you can you use that function.

Comment: Okay thank you! All I need to do is change it up a bit to match the question right?

Comment: Yea somewhat. I can do this code but the problem is the bucket sort.

Comment: What about it is the problem?

Comment: It's difficult using bucket sort on a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Oh okay. Yeah I think it may be a typo or something.

Comment: Actually I am still not getting how to do this with a 1 dimensional array and do bucket sort...

Comment: How to use the bucket sort method on a 1-dimensional array:

1. Create a `for` loop to make the array all -1
2. Using the bucket sort method you have, sort the array like this Bucket_Sort(birthYears, 15) I chose 15 because that is how many elements you have in your array.
3. Using a `for` loop, print all the element in the array

Comment: BTW twentieth century (1901 - 2000)

Comment: yeah ik, that's kinda dumb

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your assignment right, then I'd distribute the `birthYear`-values in a `10x10`-array and then write them back (ordered now) into the `birthYear`-array. Note that Bucket Sort actually would require to sort each decade, but your assignment made it little bit simpler; Concerning the data, it seems as if each birth day occurs only once. Given that, the code could look as follows:

```
void Bucket_Sort(int array[], int n) {

    // init decades array
    int decades[10][10];
    for(int dec=0;dec<10;dec++) {
        for(int year=0;year<10;year++) {
            decades[dec][year]=-1;
        }
    }

    // distribute array values to decades array
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        int val = array[i];
        int dec = val/10;
        int year = val%10;
        decades[dec][year]=val;
    }

    // write back
    int target = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        int dec = i/10;
        int year = i%10;
        int val = decades[dec][year];
        if (val>=0) {
            array[target++] = val;
        }
    }
}
```